# Angular Reactive Forms - Read / Set value from array

Tags: arrays, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-reactive-forms

I have 3 files:

- A service that collects my data from firestore and builds a form
- A component.ts file
- A component.html file

For most of my inputs I have the form correctly reading the data from the service / form builder. The area I'm having difficulty is using the Angular Material Select (dropdown) snippet.

In my component.ts file I have an array of two options for the user to select from. Once selected, that option will be saved as a string to firestore.

As you can see below, currently my HTML is currently reading from an array from its associated component.ts file. Ideally I'd like it to display the current value from firestore with the two available options available when clicking on it.

How do I provide those two options in the HTML as well as displaying the currently set value from firestore?

**Service**

```
export interface IUserSettings {
  usersetting_dateformat: string;
}

@Injectable()

export class SettingsService {

  // Database
  private settingsDocRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
  settingsDocument: Observable<any>;

  // User
  userID: string;

  // Form
  editForm = new FormGroup({});

  // User Settings Behaviour Subject 
  userSettings$: BehaviorSubject<IUserSettings>;

  constructor(
    private readonly afs: AngularFirestore, fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.editForm = fb.group({
      usersetting_dateformat: [''],
    });

    this.userSettings$ = new BehaviorSubject({
      dateformat: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    });

  }

  getSettingsData() {
    this.settingsDocRef = this.afs.doc(`settings/${this.userID}`);
    this.settingsDocument = this.settingsDocRef.snapshotChanges();
    this.settingsDocument.subscribe(value => {
      const userSettings = value.payload.data() as IUserSettings;
      this.userSettings$.next(userSettings);
      this.editForm.patchValue(this.userSettings$.getValue());
    });
  }

}
```

**Component.ts**

```
... 

  dateFormats = ["DD/MM/YYYY", "MM/DD/YYYY"];

...
```

**Component.html**

```
 <form [formGroup]="settingsService.editForm">
    <mat-select placeholder="Date Format">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let dateFormat of dateFormats" [value]="dateFormat"> {{dateFormat}} </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're unnecessarily complicating it with `BehaviourSubject` when you're already getting the value and then you're calling the `patchValue` method on the form.

You can simplify the code by removing the use of the `BehaviorSubject` like this:

```
export interface UserSettings {
  dateFormat: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {

  // Database
  private settingsDocRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
  settingsDocument: Observable<any>;

  // User
  userID: string;

  // Form
  editForm = new FormGroup({});

  constructor(
    private readonly afs: AngularFirestore,
    fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.editForm = fb.group({
      dateFormat: [],
    });
  }

  getSettingsData() {
    this.settingsDocRef = this.afs.doc(`settings/${this.userID}`);
    this.settingsDocument = this.settingsDocRef.snapshotChanges();
    this.settingsDocument.subscribe(value => {
      const userSettings = value.payload.data() as UserSettings;
      this.editForm.patchValue(userSettings);
    });
  }

}
```

And then you just need to add a `formControlName` to your template.

```
<form [formGroup]="settingsService.editForm">
  <mat-select placeholder="Date Format" formControlName="dateFormat">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let dateFormat of dateFormats" [value]="dateFormat">
      {{dateFormat}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</form>
```

This should fix your issue. Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-eg-dynamic-select-value?file=app%2Fselect-form-example.html) for your ref. Doesn't have the same code as in your eg. But should give you a context.

**TL;DR;** You just need the `FormControl` initialized with the value and then add a `formControlName` attribute to your Form Template to make this work.

Comment: Thanks Buddy! - It was just the form control name missing. The behaviour subjects are there for other areas of the app. But your answer has helped. Thank you! :)

Comment: This is brilliant. This helped me work out how to display the value in the update field based on the id passed in the url.